# why onchange  event of my textbox fires on blur - does not fire by every typed character?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, events, text, textbox

Why does the `onchange` event of my textbox fire on blur, but does not fire by every typed character ?

I want to get the entire entered text in textbox by every type by keyboard!

But `onchang`e event only is fired on blur!

Besides `onkeyup - onkeypress - onkeydown` events do not help because at first these events fire and then last entered character is applied to the textbox.

What event should I use or how can I do that?

Comment: I'm really lost after reading your question! if not key events then how will it change?

Comment: hi dear friend / test it! / when u are using onkeyup for example and type a character (such as 'a' )in the text box , so at first onkeyup fired and when u use textbox.value in onkeyup function it shows u empty string...
after onkeyup event end , the 'a' character appears on text box / but i want it on onkeyup function!
any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want keyup, keydown, or a combination of them. during the keydown handler, you can get the before-event value of the textbox. during the keyup handler, you can get the after-event value. if you're getting an empty string you're doing something wrong.

edit: here's an example demonstrating how these 2 events works. typing in the first box updates the other two.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>input</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="textin" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>keydown</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="keydownout" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>keyup</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="keyupout" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>

    var readbox = document.getElementById('textin');
    var keydownbox = document.getElementById('keydownout');
    var keyupbox = document.getElementById('keyupout');

    function keydownhandler(e) {
        keydownbox.value = readbox.value;
    }

    function keyuphandler(e) {
        keyupbox.value = readbox.value;
    }

    readbox.addEventListener('keydown', keydownhandler, false);
    readbox.addEventListener('keyup', keyuphandler, false);

</script>
```

(works in firefox/chrome)

Comment: really really thanks for your answers ....
but it is still lost one character (last entered)
some body told me to use setTimer in keyup event for getting textbox value!
i don't doing is the best or not/any idea?

Comment: i've updated my post with an example. if you're expecting a different behavior than the example provides, tell us what that might be.

Answer (score 0):

The onkeyup event fires ***after*** you've entered text:

```
onkeyup='alert(document.getElementById("myTextBox").value);'
```

Comment: i do that / but it gives me the document.getElementById("myTextBox").Length-1 character / i hove not last entered character